# NodeJS, MongoDB data modelling for CSV data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, gridfs

**Problem**

I have a CSV file with some data like below.

```
PK,title,year,length,budget,rating,votes,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8,r9,r10,mpaa,Action,Animation,Comedy,Drama,Documentary,Romance,Short
1,$,1971,121,NA,6.4,348,4.5,4.5,4.5,4.5,14.5,24.5,24.5,14.5,4.5,4.5,,0,0,1,1,0,0,0
2,$1000 a Touchdown,1939,71,NA,6,20,0,14.5,4.5,24.5,14.5,14.5,14.5,4.5,4.5,14.5,,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

The CSV file is around 5MB in size and has around 58,000+ lines like the sample above.

**Current Scenario**

Currently I am parsing the above data and converting it to objects and saving to MongoDB in an array of the objects. Something like below

```
{ PK: '1',
  title: '$',
  year: '1971',
  length: '121',
  budget: 'NA',
  rating: '6.4',
  votes: '348',
  r1: '4.5',
  r2: '4.5',
  r3: '4.5',
  r4: '4.5',
  r5: '14.5',
  r6: '24.5',
  r7: '24.5',
  r8: '14.5',
  r9: '4.5',
  r10: '4.5',
  mpaa: '',
  Action: '0',
  Animation: '0',
  Comedy: '1',
  Drama: '1',
  Documentary: '0',
  Romance: '0',
  Short: '0' }
{ PK: '2',
  title: '$1000 a Touchdown',
  year: '1939',
  length: '71',
  budget: 'NA',
  rating: '6',
  votes: '20',
  r1: '0',
  r2: '14.5',
  r3: '4.5',
  r4: '24.5',
  r5: '14.5',
  r6: '14.5',
  r7: '14.5',
  r8: '4.5',
  r9: '4.5',
  r10: '14.5',
  mpaa: '',
  Action: '0',
  Animation: '0',
  Comedy: '1',
  Drama: '0',
  Documentary: '0',
  Romance: '0',
  Short: '0' }
```

Although, when I upload the file I receive the `Document exceeds maximum allowed bson size of 16777216 bytes` error.

I tried using GridFS. The file is getting uploaded and the chunks are prepared fine as well. But, I am not sure if I can retrieve the data back as an array of objects.

I need to retrieve all the data to crunch and create some analysis.

The CSV file is one source of data. Another source would be getting data from a web service on a proprietary system where the same process is followed.

**Question**

I think there is a flaw in the data model and in the way I am saving the data to MongoDB. If yes, then what is the optimal way to handle the large amount of data.

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you saving all the rows into an array in a single document, or a document per row?

Comment: @Foo42, Yes. I am saving all rows into an array in a single document.

Comment: Try to unwind your array. Your CSV might be a collection and each document in the collection is a tuple of your CSV. Furthermore, try to parse your field into numbers i.e. year: '1971' --> year: 1971 as a string is bigger than an integer or even a float.

Comment: @GuillaumeA, The CSV data which will be imported would not have a fixed format. It can vary based on the dataset. Do you think creating a separate collevtion with each tuple of the CSV as a document would be an apt solution for this?

Comment: MongoDB is document based and schemaless. You can feed with anything you want as a document. Your documents dont have to follow the same schema in a given collection. Create only one collection and feed it with all your CSV tuples as a document regardless of their format and it should work like a charm.

Comment: Store the lines of the csv as separate documents. It'll never work to stuff a whole dataset into one document.